# Querying a column in a data frame using a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a method that pulls in a data-frame `rawDatabase`, a list of validations '`validationLists`' and a field or column name to apply the validations to in the database.

The code looks like:

```
rawDatabase = GetStandardisedField(rawDatabase,validationLists,"Status")


def GetStandardisedField(rawDatabase,validationLists,field):
    print('Standardising ', field,' ...')

    my_list = validationLists[field]

    l1=[]
    print(rawDatabase.head())
    for x in rawDatabase.field:
        print('here')
        choice = process.extractOne(x, my_list)[0]
        l1.append(choice)

    rawDatabase['choice']=l1
    rawDatabase[field] = rawDatabase['choice']
    del rawDatabase['choice']

    return rawDatabase
```

In a previous version of the code I used the actual field name, for example:

```
for x in rawDatabase.Status:
```

This used to work fine but to make my code reusable and simpler I rewrote it as:

```
for x in rawDatabase.field:
```

The code stops running 'here' and I'm wondering if Python does not allow you to use a variable to select a column in a data-frame

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame['column_name']` - is a preferred syntax of accessing DataFrame's column, compared to `DataFrame.column_name` as it allows you to:

- use variables. Example: `col='Col1'; df[col]`
- have column names as numbers
- have column names containing spaces/tabs
- have column names that shadow Numpy/Pandas method names - like: `count`, 'mean', `max`, etc. NOTE: don't use such names - it's a bad style